# Internal render, emit material and shadows

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, shadows

How to adjust the drop shadow when the scene is illuminated by object with emit material[image]

Comment: I don't think this ever was supported in Blender Internal. Switch to Blender Cycles instead, or use an actual area light in it's place.

Comment: You could simply add an alpha layered plane with the Cube's shape textured black on transparency, lay that flat behind the cube.  Vary it's opacity to get the effect required.

Comment: This works in Blender Internal only if you enable Indirect Lighting in Render tab and use Approximate gather method. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/render/blender_render/world/indirect_lighting.html